# Changing the speech recognition speed vs. accuracy trade-off in OS X Yosemite dictation

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

Is it possible to change the speech recognition speed vs. accuracy trade-off in OS X Yosemite dictation?

E.g. in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate I can change it like this:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.