# How can I speed up Enhanced Dictation's response/ processing speed?

Tags: macos, performance, voice-dictation

It takes around ten seconds to process a voice command, whereas speakable items are instantaneous.

Comment: on hat hardware ? CPU&RAM

Comment: Related: [Changing the speech recognition speed vs. accuracy trade-off in OS X Yosemite dictation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159334/20338)